# jql query parameters in javers do not support case insensitive search

Tags: javers

jql query parameters in Javers do not support case insensitive search. If the author name is 'vivek' and jql contains 'Vivek' it does not search the records from the database.

Debugging led the the query below:

```sql
SELECT state, type, version, changed_properties, managed_type, commit_pk, author, commit_date, commit_date_instant, commit_id, g.local_id, g.fragment, g.owner_id_fk, o.local_id owner_local_id, o.fragment owner_fragment, o.type_name owner_type_name
FROM jv_snapshot INNER JOIN jv_commit ON commit_pk = commit_fk INNER JOIN jv_global_id g ON g.global_id_pk = global_id_fk LEFT OUTER JOIN jv_global_id o ON o.global_id_pk = g.owner_id_fk
WHERE 1 = 1 AND author = 'Vivek'
ORDER BY snapshot_pk;
```

The actual query should be as below:

```sql
SELECT state, type, version, changed_properties, managed_type, commit_pk, author, commit_date, commit_date_instant, commit_id, g.local_id, g.fragment, g.owner_id_fk, o.local_id owner_local_id, o.fragment owner_fragment, o.type_name owner_type_name
FROM jv_snapshot INNER JOIN jv_commit ON commit_pk = commit_fk INNER JOIN jv_global_id g ON g.global_id_pk = global_id_fk LEFT OUTER JOIN jv_global_id o ON o.global_id_pk = g.owner_id_fk
WHERE 1 = 1 AND lower(author) = lower('Vivek')
ORDER BY snapshot_pk;
```

All the searches should be case insensitive. The class SelectBuilder should be changed to accomodate the issue.

Comment: And where is your question?

Comment: The question is the problem mentioned that case insensitivity is absent. Will it be possible to include the feature ? The javers querybuilder could have a flag "withCaseSensitiveSearch(true)"

Comment: This kind of flag seems legit, feel free to contribute a PR to javers

Comment: Thanks! I need much more features like 1. Sorting on author, managed_type ASC or DESC etc. Right now sorting happens only on one field 'time'. Can I submit for all such fields along with the flag. 2. Searching on 'field of interest' like a where clause on 'state' field in jv_snapshots(I know its a full scan right now). If full scan to be avoided a custom column/s with such data from state on commit so that indexing is possible.

Comment: one thing at a time, any other sorting than existing ( reverse chronological) would be very problematic in javers

Comment: I will contribute the sorting first.

Comment: I think that other sorting than by commit.timestamp desc makes sense in Javers